# S3 image file format not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, api-gateway

I want to PUT an image from Postman into my S3 bucket via API gateway using FORMDATA.
However whenever I try to open the image on S3 it downloads the image and is unable to open the image.

The image displays correctly when I upload the image by setting the upload to binary instead of form data.

I have set the binary media types in API gateway settings to */* for those of you wondering. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go To apigateway setting and add binary media type ="multipart/form-data"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this work and always see corrupt files when trying to use api gateway to handle FORMDATA. For example, wHen trying to upload files - like JPG files - using API Gateway - > Lambda function -> S3 bucket, there is a better way that works.

In the [photo asset management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html) app in the ***AWS Code Lib***, it shows a request from the React app to api gateway -> Lambda function that generates an Amazon S3 presigned URL that enables the React App to upload a JPG file to the S3 bucket. THat is, the React app uses the Presigned URL to successfully upload the image to the bucket.

Result is now I can select the Sailboat JPG image from the React App.

[image]

When I click upload, the JPG is uploaded to the S3 bucket as shown here:

[image]

Comment: It was working for me until my computer wiped . it was so easy puting to s3 using apigateway . idk what mistake i am making.

Comment: We looked into this and determined app ->api gateway->lambda function -> S3 bucket did not work well using formdata to post the JPG and using the presigned URL worked much better. The app can easily use that presigned URL to upload images to S3

Comment: You can look at all the code, inlcuding React code and the CDK  code we used to create backend resources from the link above.

Comment: will do thansk , only problem is im using an aws educate account and ive tried using presigned urls before and was a nightmare . have a deadline tonight and wnt to go back to using simple apigateway

Comment: Do you have access to SDKs (in the educate account) that where can you generate presigned URLs?

Answer (score 0):

add Content-type: image/binary-octet in api settings(binary media types) and your postman headers.
Basically the file type you are uploading should be present in both API settings  - binary media types and your postman header.
image/binary-octet is used to denote the presence of binary files. The category for this MIME type is "binary".